# No base href set error when deploying to gh-pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my angular app to Github pages and keep running into the issue.  I have my base href set in my index file, but still seem to have this issue?

> Uncaught Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

Here is my index file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Craig Graham</title>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/86a632dc3f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
<base href="/">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by changing the output path in angular.json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).